# MKMapView Draw connected lines between all points

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a list of 50+ coordinates. What is the most efficient way to draw lines between all these coordinates (should create a "circular" path because they all have a display order) that is also easy to customize (line thickness, color, etc...)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question for certain.  If you are looking for a list of points to display from end to end, then you will want to create a `MKPolyline` object from those points, making sure the points are added to the myPoints array in the order you want to connect them:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[[myPoints count]];

int i = 0;
for (Checkpoint *point in myPoints)
{
    coordinates[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([point.lat floatValue] , [point.lon floatValue]);
    i++;
}

self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count: [myPoints count]];
[mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
```

Then make sure you are implementing the delegate method `- mapView:rendererForOverlay:`.  Here's an example, but tailor it to your needs:

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer* lineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline];
    lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lineView.lineWidth = 7;
    return lineView;
}
```

However, if you really want a closed loop (circular) object, then you will want to create a `MKPolygon` object instead.  The process is quite similar; in that case replace the self.polyline initializer above with this code:

```
self.polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count: [myPoints count]];
[mapView addOverlay:self.polygon];
```

The `- mapView:rendererForOverlay:` code should remain the same I think. I haven't tested this code, but hopefully it gets you moving in the right direction.